# Best way to store variable-sized floating-point arrays in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database, in which I need to store variable-sized floating-point arrays.  These arrays are profile measurements made from a metrology tool (an ellipsometer to be specific) in a lab.  The number of points per array varies depending on what recipe the user used: the number of points currently ranges from about 5 to 199 (the largest I've seen), but the max value could increased if a user made a recipe in the future that measured more points.  Most of the arrays are 49 points (about 70%), and only 0.04% used 199 points.

Current, we are storing the arrays in a MySQL database as a as a comma-separated string as TEXT datatype.  But retrieval requires parsing and typecasting, which makes it very slow.  It also takes up about twice as much space as a 32bit binary array would.  My question is what is the best way to store this data?  I do not need to search or sort or join-to this column: just retrieve it alongside the rest of the data that goes with the measurement.

Comment: You could use a BLOB and store the raw bytes of your array of `float`. That would store in half the space and not require parsing. You did not mention what programming language you use for the client.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Thanks for the reply.  We are currently using JMP to pull the data.  I have some tools that run in Julia that pull/push data.  I'm toying with the idea of making a small app in Qt/C++ that can pull the data and send it to another application.

Answer (score 1):

There's a SQLish way of doing this, and it does not involve commas or BLOBs.

Create a `datapoints` table with three columns:

1. datapoint_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
2. measurement_id BIGINT UNSIGNED
3. datapoint FLOAT  ( or DOUBLE if you need it)

Then store your sequences of datapoints into the table, in order, in multiple rows. Each distinct measurement gets its own measurement_id value.

You can retrieve a measurement of any length with

```
SELECT datapoint 
  FROM datapoints 
 WHERE measurement_id = whatever
 ORDER BY datapoint_id;
```

This may seem like too many rows to store. But, SQL is optimized really well for this sort of use pattern.

Creating this index will make things really fast.

```
CREATE INDEX points ON datapoints
       (measurement_id, datapoint_id, datapoint);
```

And, you can make each measurement contain as few or as many datapoints as needed.

**Edit**. With this structure you can use SQL to get all sorts of descriptive statistics really easily.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       MAX(datapoint),
       MIN(datapoint),
       AVG(datapoint),
       STDEV(datapoint)
  FROM datapoints
 GROUP BY measurement_id;
```

The index I suggested will accelerate that operation too.

If you really do need arrays, consider postgresql in place of Mysql. It has them in its language.

Answer (score 1):

**All FLOATS in a single table**

A single table with about 10K rows is trivial for a database to handle.  It would have at least the FLOAT and something like recipe_id.  (See OJones's Answer for more discussion.)

**JSON**

Most languages can handle JSON.  With json_decode() and json_encode() (or however they are spelled), you can easily turn an array into a sting and vice versa.  The database version may have a `JSON` datatype or simply use `TEXT`.

**BLOB**

A BLOB gets trickier because of the typecasting that would be required; it is easier in old languages like C / C++, but harder in newer languages.  You mentioned JMP as the datasource, but not the language you are using.

Comment: Hi, Rick.  Thanks for the replay.  JMP has a scripting language (JMP Scripting Language: JSL), with which we can query the database and make tables.  Currently, a JSL script is the primary method by which data are pulled and plotted.  I also have some code written in C++/Qt as well as Julia that interacts with the database.  And there are also some tools written in VBA out there.  I'm considering rewriting the searching part of the JMP script in C++/Qt and then calling it from JMP (or making it a standalone application that can pass data to JMP).